# Parsing math formula XML<-> Latex in Perl or XSLT

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I want to write a simple parser XML <-> Latex. I'm new in Perl or XSLT and I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me? In example this is my formula:

[image]

In Latex:

```
\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{2}{x+y}}
```

And my proposition of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<formula>
    <numerator>
        <numerator>
            <numerator>1</numerator>
            <denominator>2</denominator>
                <sign>+</sign>
            <numerator>1</numerator>
            <denominator>y</denominator>
        </numerator>
        <denominator>
            <numerator>2</numerator>
            <denominator>x</denominator>
        </denominator>
    </numerator>
    <denominator>
        <numerator>2</numerator>
        <denominator>x+y</denominator>
    </denominator>
</formula>
```

Comment: Do you already know about [Presentation MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathml#Presentation_MathML)?

Comment: Yes. Answer from Mirod is good but i don't know how to parse this Mathml to latex. I want to parse only fractions like this without other functions but in Perl I only know how to read and how to save to file

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the first comment on your question:why re-invent the wheel? Why not use MathML?

There are converters from LaTeX to MathML, for example [MathToWeb](http://www.mathtowebonline.com/) http://www.mathtowebonline.com/ . The resulting MathML for your expression would be this:

```
<!-- begin MathToWeb -->
<!-- (your LaTeX) $\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{2}{x+y}}$ -->
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<mrow>
    <mfrac linethickness="1">
        <mrow>
            <mfrac linethickness="1">
                <mrow>
                    <mfrac linethickness="1">
                        <mn>1</mn>
                        <mn>2</mn>
                    </mfrac>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <mfrac linethickness="1">
                        <mn>1</mn>
                        <mi>y</mi>
                    </mfrac>
                </mrow>
                <mrow>
                    <mfrac linethickness="1">
                        <mn>2</mn>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                    </mfrac>
                </mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
            <mfrac linethickness="1">
                <mn>2</mn>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <mi>y</mi>
                </mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mrow>
    </mfrac>
</mrow>
</math>
<!-- end MathToWeb -->
```

This can be displayed in browsers, either natively (Firefox at least), or using [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which is a javascript math rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your request. This is a good idea about Mathml, but I want to create my own parser Latex<->Mathml in Perl or XSLT and this is very big problem for me

Comment: The parser could not be in XSLT since LaTeX is not XML. Beyonf that. I am not sure why you would want to do this, I am pretty sure there are open-source LaTeX parsers available.

Comment: This is a part of my homework to write a script which translate math formulas (only simple like this in link in my post) from XML to Latex and from Latex to XML. Best way will be from mathml to latex and from latex to mathml